# How can i get all my saved posts in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have to entities like User and Food. User can save food posts. I am trying to getting all saved posts of user but how can i do this? I am writing hibernate query in food repository but i can't access saved food posts.
Here is my code:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    private List<Food> savedRecipes;
}
```

Food class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class Food extends BaseEntity {

    private String foodName;
    private String recipe;
  
    @OneToMany
    private List<Category> categoryList;

 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

}
```

Repository Code:

```
@Repository
public interface FoodRepository extends JpaRepository<Food,Long> {

    List<Food> findAllByFoodNameContaining(String searchedValue);

    List<Food> findAllByCategoryListInAndDeletedFalse(List<Category> categoryList);

    List<Food> findAllByUserId(Long id);

    List<Food> findAllByUserSavedRecipes(Long id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
`List <Food> findAllByUser (User user);`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get All User's saved food by call below methods

1st:   `List<Food> result = User.getSavedRecipes()`

2nd:   `List<Food> result = FoodRepository.findAllByUserId(Long id)`